# Showing hidden files in specific directories?

Tags: finder, macos

I use this command quite often to show hidden files on my machine:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Is there a way to show all hidden files only in specific directories. E.g. I want to be able to see stuff like .ssh

However I don't want my desktop and every folder to show this damn .DS_Store files. Is there a trick to so?

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to hide specific files/folders from Finder (and any Open/Save dialogs) there is always

```
chflags hidden FILENAME
```

If, on the other hand, you only want to make specific dot-files/directories (like .ssh or .bashrc) visible in Finder, you may be better of with creating non-dotted symlinks

```
ln -s .bashrc bashrc
ln -s .ssh ssh
```

and using them to access the files where needed.