# Is it possible to keep dot files with specific extension unhidden in Finder?

Tags: terminal, finder, filesystem, macos

I know that all the hidden files (dot files) can be viewed in Finder by using the keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

or by running the following in Terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true`

But, is it possible to change a dot file with specific extension to always show in Finder? Specifically, I want the `.vscode` to be always visible in Finder. I don't want to show all the hidden files, and I am trying to do this without having to use the shortcut or always run a command in the Terminal.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Note that files with extension `.vscode` won't be hidden such as `something.vscode`. macOS by default hides any file/directory name starting with with a dot. Thus `.vscode` file (if any) will be hidden.

Comment: @NimeshNeema yep I am familiar with this behavior, however, for a few reasons, I am wondering if it is possible to change this behavior in Finder. Wondering if it is possible to change the behavior but only have it affect an unnamed .vscode file or say an .gittignore file

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about the `.vscode` *folder* in your **Home** *folder*, as I have one there too from the **Visual Studio Code.app** install.

If you do not want to permanently show *hidden files* or use the **⌘⇧.** *keyboard shortcut*, then this is what I'd do.

Open **Terminal** to the *directory* containing the `.vscode` *folder* and use the following *command* to create a *symlink*:

```
ln -s .vscode ' .vscode'
```

Note that the *symlink* has a *leading space* in its *name*; however, it's the only way to be visually accurate, per se, seeing it shown in **Finder** to have the appearance that it is a *dot file* without actually showing the *hidden* `.vscode` *folder*.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out:

[Showing hidden files in specific directories?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27443/showing-hidden-files-in-specific-directories)

I think it provides a good workaround. Not sure that there is anyway directly to make that one .someFile type not hidden.